# How to detect Updated textbox with Linq

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

-->VB.Net VS2010

If this is a stupid question, then let me know. I can't just figure it out.
First of all, this is my question. How do I detect the changed value on those text boxes?

I have an idea that I create a another string values that have the original values and compare them right before saving or form closing event. This sample just have 3 text boxes,  but I have 50 + text boxes on my one form. I can do it that way, but that is not really smart idea.

Can I use abcDB.SubmitChanges() to detect any data changes on text boxes?

```
Dim sqlQuery = (From obj in abcDB.HelloWorld 
               Select obj.Fname, obj.Lname, obj.PhoneNumber).FirstOrDefault()

me.textboxFname.text = sqlQuery.Fname
me.textboxLname.text = sqlQuery.Lname
me.textboxPhoneNumber.text = sqlQuery.PhoneNumber
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you really want to do is called 'data binding'.  Lots of tutorials about that aroud the web and any book about VB.NET will have at least 1 chapter dedicated to it.